# Две функции в одном javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть строчка

```
document.getElementById("calc-price").onclick = calcprice;
```

я не могу поменять на

```
$('#calc-price').onclick = calcprice;
```

`Jquery` подключен но не работает эта строка. Не понимаю что делаю не так

===========================================================================

У меня стоят по очереди 2 функции

- первая пишет переменную в такой ***ID***

  ```
  $('#price-delivery-ukraine').text($pricetotal);
  ```
- вторая пишет переменную в другой ***ID***

  ```
  $('#price-total').text($pricetotal);
  ```

Две функции должны срабатывать после нажатия одной и той же кнопки

```
document.getElementById("calc-price").onclick = calcprice;
document.getElementById("calc-price").onclick = calcpricegreen;
```

Работает только одна из них. Почему? Можно ли в одном js на одно кнопку повесить вывод нескольких переменных

Answer (score 3):

В jQuery используйте метод `$(...).click(function () {...})`

Проблема с двумя функциями подряд очень проста - вторая функция переопределяет первую.
Чтобы именно добавить функцию без jQuery, нужно использовать метод addEventListener